# How to permit array of hashes in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create multiple "Absence"s by posting:

```
Parameters: {"absences"=>[{"user_id"=>1, "lesson_id"=>25,
"excused"=>true}, {"user_id"=>2, "lesson_id"=>25, "excused"=>true}]}
```

However, I am not able to whitelist this format in the controller. I attempted to follow the solution from "[How to use strong parameters with an objects array in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595364/rails-strong-parameters-with-objects-array)".

In my case:

```
def absence_params
  params.permit(absences: [:user_id, :lesson_id, :excused])
end
```

I get

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'absences' for Absence.):
```

Then I tried:

```
Parameters: {"absence"=>[{"user_id"=>1, "lesson_id"=>25,
"excused"=>true}, {"user_id"=>2, "lesson_id"=>25, "excused"=>true}]}

def absence_params
  params.permit(:absence, array: [:user_id, :lesson_id, :excused])
end
```

and got:

```
Unpermitted parameters: :absence, :format
```

---

----   ***Resolved***  ----

1. The gem 'cancancan' was not allowing me to create using an array.
2. If you have an issue permitting an array in the strong params, try

---

```
params.require(:absences).map do |p|
  p.permit(:user_id, :lesson_id, :excused)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters permit code is correct:

```rb
require "bundler/inline"

gemfile(ENV['INSTALL'] == '1') do
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem "actionpack", "6.0.2.2"
  gem "activesupport", "6.0.2.2"
end

require "active_support/core_ext"
require "action_controller/metal/strong_parameters"
require "minitest/autorun"


class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_stuff

    params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
      "absences"=>[
        {"user_id"=>1, "unpermitted_param" => 123, "lesson_id"=>25, "excused"=>true},
        {"user_id"=>2, "lesson_id"=>25, "excused"=>true}
      ]
    })

    assert_equal(
      {
        "absences"=>[
          {"user_id"=>1, "lesson_id"=>25, "excused"=>true},
          {"user_id"=>2, "lesson_id"=>25, "excused"=>true}
        ]
      },
      params.permit(absences: [:user_id, :lesson_id, :excused]).to_h
    )
  end
end
```

The error comes from some other place, most likely you're trying to do something like `Absence.create(absence_params)`, which will only work for single records.

To create an array at once you should adjust other relevant code accordingly, for example:

1. Manually handle the array like:

   ```
   @absenses = params["absences"].map do |raw_absense_params|
     Absense.create!(raw_absense_params.permit(:user_id, :lesson_id, :excused))
   end
   ```
2. Employ `accepts_nested_attrubutes_for :absenses` for the parent model if you have any (probably `Lesson`). The code for this will be cleaner, as Rails will handle most things for you, like cases when not all instances can be saved because of validation, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I am getting "Unpermitted parameter: :format." and "ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'absences' for Absence.)" even when I do not attempt to use `absence_params` :/

Comment: Turns out it was the gem 'cancancan' that did not accept arrays... Thanks!